# The fsolve matlab function not converging

Tags: matlab

I have a system of 6 equations in 6 unknowns and I am trying to solve it using fsolve. A strange thing arises though. When I keep 6 in eq's in 6 un's as they are and call fsolve they solver does not converge and is very slow. But when I reduce equations in 5 with 6 unknowns (I can do this by substituting one of my equations in the rest) and by using the **'levenberg-marquardt'** the solver converges really fast and reaches a solution. While the solutions I get are good I am not sure if they are correct and I cannot understand why this happens. I also tried to set as initial values in the 6x6 case the solution I got from the 5x6 case but again the fsolve is not converging. I don't know if it is a mathematical problem or fsolve's problem

Any thoughts? 
Thank you
p.s I am not posting the code, it is really big, My system is first written in symbolic and then i substitute symbolic variables with numeric so as to solve it with fsolve.

```
function f=examplegeneral(x);

beta11=0.5; beta12=0.5; beta21=0.5; beta22=0.5; b11=0.5; b12=0.5; b21=0.5; b22=0.5; v1=0.5; v2=0.5;

f(1)=x(2)*(1/beta11)^beta11*((x(1) + x(4) + x(6))/beta12)^beta12 - v1*(b12*x(1)^2 + b11)^(1/2) - x(2)*(x(4) + x(6))*(1/beta11)^beta11*((x(1) + x(4) + x(6))/beta12)^(beta12 - 1);
f(2)=x(3)*(1/beta21)^beta21*((x(1) + x(5) + x(6))/beta22)^beta22 - v2*(b22*x(1)^2 + b21)^(1/2) - x(3)*(x(5) + x(6))*(1/beta21)^beta21*((x(1) + x(5) + x(6))/beta22)^(beta22 - 1);
f(3)=(x(2)*(x(4) + x(6))*(beta12 - 1)*(1/beta11)^beta11*((x(1) + x(4) + x(6))/beta12)^(beta12 - 2))/beta12 - (x(2)*(beta12 - 1)*(1/beta11)^beta11*((x(1) + x(4) + x(6))/beta12)^(beta12 - 2)*((b12*x(1)*v1)/(b12*x(1)^2 + b11)^(1/2) - x(2)*(1/beta11)^beta11*((x(1) + x(4) + x(6))/beta12)^(beta12 - 1) + (x(2)*(x(4) + x(6))*(beta12 - 1)*(1/beta11)^beta11*((x(1) + x(4) + x(6))/beta12)^(beta12 - 2))/beta12))/(beta12*((b12^2*x(1)^2*v1)/(b12*x(1)^2 + b11)^(3/2) - (b22*v2)/(b22*x(1)^2 + b21)^(1/2) - (b12*v1)/(b12*x(1)^2 + b11)^(1/2) + (b22^2*x(1)^2*v2)/(b22*x(1)^2 + b21)^(3/2) + (x(2)*(beta12 - 1)*(1/beta11)^beta11*((x(1) + x(4) + x(6))/beta12)^(beta12 - 2))/beta12 + (x(3)*(beta22 - 1)*(1/beta21)^beta21*((x(1) + x(5) + x(6))/beta22)^(beta22 - 2))/beta22));
f(4)=(x(3)*(x(5) + x(6))*(beta22 - 1)*(1/beta21)^beta21*((x(1) + x(5) + x(6))/beta22)^(beta22 - 2))/beta22 - (x(3)*(beta22 - 1)*(1/beta21)^beta21*((x(1) + x(5) + x(6))/beta22)^(beta22 - 2)*((b22*x(1)*v2)/(b22*x(1)^2 + b21)^(1/2) - x(3)*(1/beta21)^beta21*((x(1) + x(5) + x(6))/beta22)^(beta22 - 1) + (x(3)*(x(5) + x(6))*(beta22 - 1)*(1/beta21)^beta21*((x(1) + x(5) + x(6))/beta22)^(beta22 - 2))/beta22))/(beta22*((b12^2*x(1)^2*v1)/(b12*x(1)^2 + b11)^(3/2) - (b22*v2)/(b22*x(1)^2 + b21)^(1/2) - (b12*v1)/(b12*x(1)^2 + b11)^(1/2) + (b22^2*x(1)^2*v2)/(b22*x(1)^2 + b21)^(3/2) + (x(2)*(beta12 - 1)*(1/beta11)^beta11*((x(1) + x(4) + x(6))/beta12)^(beta12 - 2))/beta12 + (x(3)*(beta22 - 1)*(1/beta21)^beta21*((x(1) + x(5) + x(6))/beta22)^(beta22 - 2))/beta22));
f(5)=(x(2)*(x(4) + x(6))*(beta12 - 1)*(1/beta11)^beta11*((x(1) + x(4) + x(6))/beta12)^(beta12 - 2))/beta12 - (((x(2)*(beta12 - 1)*(1/beta11)^beta11*((x(1) + x(4) + x(6))/beta12)^(beta12 - 2))/beta12 + (x(3)*(beta22 - 1)*(1/beta21)^beta21*((x(1) + x(5) + x(6))/beta22)^(beta22 - 2))/beta22)*((x(2)*(x(4) + x(6))*(beta12 - 1)*(1/beta11)^beta11*((x(1) + x(4) + x(6))/beta12)^(beta12 - 2))/beta12 + (x(3)*(x(5) + x(6))*(beta22 - 1)*(1/beta21)^beta21*((x(1) + x(5) + x(6))/beta22)^(beta22 - 2))/beta22))/((b12^2*x(1)^2*v1)/(b12*x(1)^2 + b11)^(3/2) - (b22*v2)/(b22*x(1)^2 + b21)^(1/2) - (b12*v1)/(b12*x(1)^2 + b11)^(1/2) + (b22^2*x(1)^2*v2)/(b22*x(1)^2 + b21)^(3/2) + (x(2)*(beta12 - 1)*(1/beta11)^beta11*((x(1) + x(4) + x(6))/beta12)^(beta12 - 2))/beta12 + (x(3)*(beta22 - 1)*(1/beta21)^beta21*((x(1) + x(5) + x(6))/beta22)^(beta22 - 2))/beta22) + (x(3)*(x(5) + x(6))*(beta22 - 1)*(1/beta21)^beta21*((x(1) + x(5) + x(6))/beta22)^(beta22 - 2))/beta22;
f(6)=1/((b12^2*x(1)^2*v1)/(b12*x(1)^2 + b11)^(3/2) - (b22*v2)/(b22*x(1)^2 + b21)^(1/2) - (b12*v1)/(b12*x(1)^2 + b11)^(1/2) + (b22^2*x(1)^2*v2)/(b22*x(1)^2 + b21)^(3/2) + (x(2)*(beta12 - 1)*(1/beta11)^beta11*((x(1) + x(4) + x(6))/beta12)^(beta12 - 2))/beta12 + (x(3)*(beta22 - 1)*(1/beta21)^beta21*((x(1) + x(5) + x(6))/beta22)^(beta22 - 2))/beta22);
```

and then i call

```
x0=[0.8,0.05,0.05,0.01,0.01,-0.01]; % This is the vector of initial values.

options = optimset('Display','iter','MaxFunEvals',1e+15,'MaxIter',1000000000);
[sol,exitflag,fval]=fsolve('examplegeneral',x0,options)
```

Comment: Well, it's really difficult to answer this without seeing the code. Can you reduce the code to the minimum needed to replicate the issue?

Comment: there are 3 different m-files needed to run the issue. Im new to stack-exchange. Is there a way to upload the m-files?

Comment: No. We don't want to see the whole code, just the minimum amount needed to reproduce the issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how to ask a good question.

Comment: i edited the problem as you proposeed above

Comment: It looks like there is no solution, the cost function reaches ~0.12 very quickly, depending on which algorithm you choose, and then stays there, it doesn't go any further towards zero. That leads me to believe there is no solution. You may want to consider simplifying your equations, they are ginormous, which probably doesn't help...